# How can I get child of loop HTMLCollection?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working with html and in this job I would like get one help from you

Look the following question

I have this div

```html
<div class="my-class">
  <h1 class="title">Test 1</h1>
</div>

<div class="my-class">
  <h1 class="title">Test 2</h1>
</div>

<div class="my-class">
  <h1 class="title">Test 3</h1>
</div>

<div class="my-class">
  <h1 class="title">Test 4</h1>
</div>
```

I would to do one loop to get the text from h1 to hide if text is `Test 1`

I'm trying like this:

```
var htmlCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('my-class')
console.log(htmlCollection);
Array.prototype.slice.call(htmlCollection).forEach(element => {
 console.log(element);
});
```

or

Like this:

```
var htmlCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('bs-media-item-card-array-1')
var BoxArray = Array.from(htmlCollection);
console.log(BoxArray);
```

Or

```
var htmlCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('bs-media-item-card-array-1')
for(index of htmlCollection){
  console.log(index);
}
```

Or

```
for(index in htmlCollection){
   if(index <= htmlCollection.length) {
       console.log(htmlCollection[index]);
    }
 }
```

The return from

```
var htmlCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('my-class')
```

Is this

```
HTMLCollection []
0: div.my-class
1: div.my-class
2: div.my-class
3: div.my-class
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: HTMLCollection
```

**UPDATE**

Sometimes I tried to use like this, too

```
<div class="my-class">
    <a class="my-subclass">
      <h1 class="title">Test 2</h1>
   </a>
</div>

 <div class="my-class">
   <a class="my-subclass">
      <h1 class="title">Test 3</h1>
   </a>
 </div>
```

Thanks for help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `querySelector()` to find the `class="title"` element in the div and test its text.

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.my-class')
divs.forEach(div => {
  if (div.querySelector(".title").innerText == 'Test 1') {
    div.classList.add('hidden');
  }
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class">
  <h1 class="title">Test 1</h1>
</div>

<div class="my-class">
  <a class="my-subclass">
    <h1 class="title">Test 2</h1>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="my-class">
  <a class="my-subclass">
    <h1 class="title">Test 3</h1>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="my-class">
  <h1 class="title">Test 4</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I might change the variable name to `nodeList` to reflect what QSA returns.

Comment: I've changed it to something that describes it rather than the type

Comment: If I put console I have this `NodeList []`

Comment: Actually my h3 is in <a>

Comment: It doesn't matter. `querySelector()` will search for it at any depth inside the div.

Comment: I added `console.log(divs)`, it's not empty.

Comment: I copied your code for my local. I get this result `NodeList []
length: 0`

Comment: You must have changed something, because it works here.

Comment: Update the question and show the actual HTML.

Comment: I've updated my code to be like your new HTML. It still works.

Comment: It worked out! It was the position of my javascript in my html file. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can combine everything in `querySelectorAll()`,
then use `element.closest()`

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('div.my-class > h1.title')
  .forEach( elm =>
    {
    if (elm.textContent.includes('Test 1'))
       elm.closest('div.my-class').classList.add('noDisplay')
    })
```

```css
.noDisplay {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class">
  <h1 class="title">Test 1</h1>
</div>

<div class="my-class">
  <h1 class="title">Test 2</h1>
</div>

<div class="my-class">
  <h1 class="title">Test 3</h1>
</div>

<div class="my-class">
  <h1 class="title">Test 4</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Get all the h1 elements with a class of title inside elements with a class of my-class and filter the ones where the text is Test 1

const elementsToHide =
[...document.querySelectorAll('div.my-class > h1.title')]
.filter(node => node.innerText === 'Test 1');

//Hide them
elementsToHide.forEach(h1 => h1.classList.add('hide'));
```

```css
.hide {
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="my-class">
  <h1 class="title">Test 1</h1>
</div>

<div class="my-class">
  <h1 class="title">Test 2</h1>
</div>

<div class="my-class">
  <h1 class="title">Test 3</h1>
</div>

<div class="my-class">
  <h1 class="title">Test 4</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: When I put console.log in elementsToHide I have `[]`

Comment: I tryed in my local, but didnt work

Comment: Do you have something different in your local code than the scripts you've posted? Because you could run the snippet and see that it works. Maybe you can provide some additional information and then I could see why?

Comment: I think it was the position of the script in my html file.